# Should a plist file update when data is saved to it?

Tags: swift, swift3, plist

I'm aware that this has been discussed in many other ways, but I have tried using previous answers and have remained stuck on this problem for over a week.

I am trying to gather questions from one plist file (with unique question IDs) and then saving that question ID with the user's answer into another plist.

I am having no issues loading the questions, but the following code doesn't seem to update the AnsweredQs plist file.

It prints "true" which suggests the write worked, but when I return to xcode there is no change to the plist.

```
func documentFilePath(fileName: String) -> String {
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    return fileURL.path
}

func saveQuestion(ans: String) {

    let path = documentFilePath(fileName: "AnsweredQs.plist")
    let data = NSMutableDictionary()

    data.setValue(QuestionView.questionID, forKey: "id")
    data.setValue(ans, forKey: "answer")
    data.setValue(Date(), forKey: "date")
    data.setValue(loadQuestionData(id: QuestionView.questionID).expiry, forKey: "expiry")
    data.setValue(loadQuestionData(id: QuestionView.questionID).maxAge, forKey: "max-age")

    let didWriteSucess = data.write(toFile: path, atomically: false)

    print(didWriteSucess)

    print(data)

 }
```

In addition to this, I am wanting to set up a check when the question is randomly generated so that only unanswered questions are selected for the user to answer. I've started work on this (although this code is not complete) and it doesn't seem to ever find anything in the AnsweredQs plist, suggesting further that the save isn't actually working.

```
func checkQuestion(id: Any) -> Bool {
    var trueOrFalse = Bool()

    if QuestionView.questionNumber >= 1 {

        var questionDict: NSDictionary = [:]

        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"AnsweredQs", withExtension: ".plist"),
            let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) as? [String:Any] {
            print(dict)
            questionDict = dict as NSDictionary

            let allValues = [questionDict]

            if allValues.count != 0 {

                if allValues.description == id as! String{

                    trueOrFalse = true
                    print("true\(allValues)")

                } else {

                    trueOrFalse = false
                    print("false\(allValues)")

                }

            }

        }

    } else {
        trueOrFalse = false
        print("didn't check")
    }

    return(trueOrFalse)
```

It's my first app and I'm trying to figure it all out myself, but I've gotten myself so stuck that all I was left with was to ask here.

Thanks in advance x

Comment: Have you double checked that the path you are asking the system to write to is the path that you expect it to be?  Print out "path" right after your call to  documentFilePath.

Comment: It further looks like your two bits of code are looking for the answered questions file in two different places.   One appears to be trying to save the answered questions to the user's documents folder, but then the other is trying to load the file from the application bundle.  (You should not try to write data into the application bundle.)

Comment: double check , app generated content should be stored in Application Document folder not other place .

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for your help @ScottThompson and Shobhakar, I have only just had a chance to properly look at this again. Scott, this makes so much sense. I have now updated the code so that I am always working with file manager rather than bundle and it all seems to be running - wooohoooo. But is there a way I can see the file being created? It's not saving exactly how I'd like, so I'd like to adjust and then see how it looks etc. Thanks again. You're both amazing x

Comment: You're generating, or discovering the file path.  Just print out that path and look at it.  If you're working on an Mac OS X application you should be able to visit the file.  If you're on iOS you should be able to visit the file when your run in the simulator... on device you would have to write your own code to display the file.

Comment: Thanks @ScottThompson! It's all figured out :) x